# Find all blobs below a certain path in Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to list all blobs that start with a certain path and filename.

I have this path: `"files/folder1/folder2/abcdef"`

These files exist

```
`"files/folder1/folder2/abcdef_100_100.jpg"`
`"files/folder1/folder2/abcdef_200_200.jpg"`
`"files/folder1/folder2/abcdef_800_600.jpg"`
```

Note that they all start with the same beginning, and just the end of the filename is different. I don't know what endings exist, just that there will most likely be more than one.

For a single file with a complete path this code works great.

```
CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = _blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
```

So far I have tried and failed with the following code for getting all files matching the direcoty and start of file name:

```
var imageFiles = _blobContainer.ListBlobs(startingPath, true, BlobListingDetails.None);
```

and

```
var blobDirectory = _blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(startingPath);
var imageFiles = blobDirectory .ListBlobs();
```

Both of these return an empty result.

How should I accomplish this?

P.S. The data must not be filtered client side. There will be thousands of files.

P.P.S If I have to filter the contents of the last folder (`folder2`) that would be fine, there will be less than 100 files in each folder at that level.

**Update 1**
this also does not work.

```
// returns files/folder1/folder2
var dirPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(startingPath); 

var ss = _blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(dirPath);
var imageFiles = ss.ListBlobs();
```

Comment: What if you set `startingPath` to contain only `files/folder1/folder2/`? Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListBlobs` should work the way you expect. Make sure you have no issues with case sensitivity and that you have the right value for the container name.

Full example:

```
var acc = Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connstring");
var blobClient = acc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("files"); // might also be different in your case, not sure with the info in the question
var blobs = container.ListBlobs("folder1/folder2/abcdef", true); // make sure to not put the container name here
foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(blob.Uri);
}
```

Comment: It worked. I had a slash in front of the path and it seems very picky and not able to resolve that. Got all the files I wanted.  Thank you.